# how to add fishpig "blog" link to main navigation in magento

Tags: magento, fishpig

I'm using Magento WordPress Integration I'm wondering how to add fishpig "blog" link to main navigation in magento ? Currently it's only adding a link to my top header navigation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above answer correctly shows how to add a link to your toplinks, however this is included in the extension by default. If you want to do this, you can enable/disable this from the extension's configuration area.

If you are referring to the Topmenu (the Category menu), it is now possible to create a custom Menu in the WordPress Admin and have this automatically added to your Magento Topmenu.

To do this, create a menu in WordPress. If you only want a single link to your blog, create a menu with this just this link in. Next, login to the Magento Admin and go to the configuration area for WordPress Integration. Under the fieldset labelled 'Menu', you can enable menu integration and select your newly created menu.

This will only work if your theme uses the Magento Topmenu block, which is the default menu block for Magento 1.7. Some custom themes use a custom menu extension for this menu and it is highly unlikely that this custom extension will call the necessary event.

As always, ensure you are using the latest version of WordPress Integration as this feature is quite new and has only recently been added.